# Determine the average time taken to process 13 instructions with this system?

Tags: cpu-architecture, instructions

*Question:*

A non-pipelined system takes 7.5 ns to process an instruction with a clock cycle of 1.5 ns. The same instruction can be processed in a 5-segment pipeline.

The instruction set architecture of the non-pipelined system is replaced with a CISC design. Empirical tests show that for a typical program, 81% of the instructions take only 3 ns to complete and 19% of the instructions take 7.5 ns. Determine the average time taken to process 13 instructions with this system to one decimal place.

*Answer:*

The average time per instruction is given by

> fi + ti

where

fi = fraction of instruction of class i

ti = execution time for fraction fi

Putting the values, we get the average time per instruction

= (0.81 * 3 ns) + (0.19 * 7.5 ns)

= 3.855 ns

Thus, time to execute 13 instructions

= (Number of instructions) * (Average execution time per instruction)

= 13 * (3.855 ns)

**= 50.115 ns**

I do not understand why they did (0.81 * 3 ns) + (0.19 * 7.5 ns), how does doing this give you the average time per instruction?

Comment: Instruction A takes 3 ns and has a chance of 81% to be chosen.
Instruction B takes 7.5 ns and has a chance of 19% to be chosen.
This means if we look at 100 instructions.
Instruction A is executed 81 times instruction B is executed 19 times.
now we calculate the  time.
Total time=81 * 3 ns + 19 * 7.5 ns 
Now we divide by 100 to get time by instruction.
time by instruction = (81 * 3 ns + 19 * 7.5 ns) /100

Comment: If it takes (on average) 30 minutes to answer a [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question, but 90% is obvious, so it will only take 5 minutes to answer, the average changes to (0.9*5)+(0.1*30) = 7.5 minutes.  (but this is what your teacher tried to explain already?)

Comment: hmm wdym by 90% is obvious? 90% of what is obvious? can you do another analogy please @Luuk

Comment: Luuk was showing how the same weighted-average math can apply to other things, like answering questions.  Where 10% of the questions are hard, and 90% are easy (fast to answer).

Comment: okay, I have a question. Why wouldn't this work: 7.5 + 3 / 2 to find the average time per instruction? @PeterCordes

Comment: Because the instruction mix isn't 50:50.  Consider whether your formula would still make sense if 99 out of every 100 instructions are the 3ns fast ones, and only 1 out of every 100 is the slow 7.5ns type.  (Or 0 out of 100 vs. 100 out of 100.)  Obviously the average time is lower when more of them are the fast kind, so the formula needs to include that weighting somehow.

Comment: Probability is something I really struggle with, it has and will always be the hardest topic in my computer science course. I still do not fully grasp the (0.81 * 3 ns) + (0.19 * 7.5 ns) part. Is this something most people should know? Is this just how averages work? @PeterCordes

Comment: Yeah, that's just how weighted averages work.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Basic_example.  The section after that uses pretty formal / technical math language, but does make the key point that the weights sum to 1.0.  And the actual example itself in the first section should be pretty comprehensible.